# Syntax error in if statement in Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute the below code in Python 3.4.2 shell. While pressing enter after writing the else statement, I am getting a syntax error.

How to close if statement?

```
    >>> x=12
    >>> if x <0 and x > 15 :
        print (x)
        else:

    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: In Python indentation matters

Comment: `x` will never be both less than zero and also more than fifteen.

Comment: the `print` needs to be indented as being part of the body of the `if` statement, and `else:` needs to be followed by something.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is so badly garbled that I cannot tell what you are trying to do or how to correct it.  Please read the Python tutorial to learn basic syntax.  For conditional assignment, you have two choices.  Here are examples.

```
x = 'hi' if y > 10 else 'lo'

if y > 10:
    x = 'hi'
else:
    x = 'lo'
```

The conditional statement form can be used for more than conditional assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent properly as well as finish the statements off

`if x < 0 and x > 15:
    print x
else:
    print 'No'`

FYI a value cannot be less than 0 and simultaneously greater than 15. You may be looking for an 'or' instead of 'and'

Good luck!